# Flex Slider and Bootstrap's Required jQuery Aren't Mixing

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, flexslider

I am trying to add Bootstrap 4 to an existing site.Everything went fine until I tried to add the jQuery Files that Bootstrap required.

When I add t following, the Flex Slider slide disappears:

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

When I remove the code, it returns. I am currently trying to do something with Bootstrap and I think it needs that jQuery file.

How do I get Flex Slider to play nicely with jQuery?